# how to change the antd carousel dot shape and color with styled component

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

tried to change the antd carousel dots styles, it can be able to implement with **CSS** but not with **styled-components**(CSS is not allowed in my project). as im new to front-end dont know the proper solution for this.

here is the code example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-opnojd-rfagtz?file=index.js

thanks in advance :)[image: antd carousel]

Answer (score 5):

When using styled-component, the style would be applied with className `sc-...`.

In your case, its style would be applied in `div` containing `.slick-slider`.

But, `.ant-carousel` is className for parent of that.

So, if it was included in the selector, style will be not applied.

Try this.

```js
const CarouselWrapper = styled(Carousel)`
  > .slick-dots li button {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  > .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my SCSS style. First, I selected the class of Antd and then added styles to it.

```
[class~='ant-carousel'] {
            [class~='slick-slider'] {
              li button {
                    width: 6px;
                    height: 6px;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                  }
               li.slick-active button {
                    width: 7px;
                    height: 7px;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                  }
            }
           
        }
```